# Getting error "Cannot resolve symbol FirebaseAuth" in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Getting error "Cannot resolve symbol FirebaseAuth" in Android Studio

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        firebaseAuth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    }
}
```

I added and sync the following dependencies,

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0"
```

There is no error in creating a FirebaseAuth variable. After I cleaned the project but still I'm getting error at this line:

```
 firebaseAuth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

Comment: Whats this ?   `firebaseAuth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance();` where is the assignment ?

Answer (score 2):

This is not supposed to be like this

```
 firebaseAuth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

it should be like this

```
   firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

full code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

}
}
```

Comment: why mAutfirebaseAuthh?

Comment: thanks @JohnJoe it was just a type mistake. corrected